# G++ link against psapi in Cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, cygwin, static-libraries

I have a C++ project which I used to build with Visual C++. In the project I used:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi")
```

in order to link against `psapi`.

G++ does not seem to support this syntax, though. From what I understand you would have to pass a `-l` flag with the name of the library in order to link against it.

I tried `-lpsapi.lib` and `-lpsapi`.
But gcc wasn't able to find it.
So I searched where I could find it and apparently it is in `/lib/w32api/libpsapi.a`. So I tried `-llibpsapi.a` and `-llibpsapi`, but it is still not able to find it.
So I tried to add the path using the `-L` flag like so `-L/lib/w32api`, but it would still not find it.
Then I tried adding two environment variables instead of the `-L` flag:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/w32api
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/w32api
```

But it is still not working.

The error message is:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -llibpsapi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And my last attempt was:

```
g++ -llibpsapi -o Example.exe Stuff.cpp Example.cpp -static
```

If I leave the `-l` flag out entirely, then I get these errors btw:

```
/tmp/cctDMx8f.o:Stuff.cpp:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `EnumProcessModules'
/tmp/cctDMx8f.o:Stuff.cpp:(.text+0x139): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `EnumProcessModules'
/tmp/cctDMx8f.o:Stuff.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `EnumProcessModules'
/tmp/cctDMx8f.o:Stuff.cpp:(.text+0x181): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `EnumProcessModules'
/tmp/cctDMx8f.o:Stuff.cpp:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `GetModuleBaseNameA'
/tmp/cctDMx8f.o:Stuff.cpp:(.text+0x1db): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `GetModuleBaseNameA'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. First of all I had to use `-lpsapi` and the second important part was that I don't insert it before the `-o` flag. The following worked just fine:

```
g++ -o Example.exe Stuff.cpp Example.cpp -static -lpsapi
```